# Linking to a document by class name instead of id?

Tags: html

Is there a possible way to do `href=".edit"` to make it be a class?

Because right now I have this:

```
<a href="#edit" >Edit</a>

<div id="edit" ></div>
<div id="edit" ></div>
<div id="edit" ></div>
<div id="edit" ></div>
```

But I have lots of `<div id="edit" ></div>` because it php echoes from a database. It only links to the first one. How can I change this?

Comment: You can't, so far as I know, but be aware that the `id` of an element ***must*** be unique within the document. Multiple elements using the same `id` is invalid HTML.

Comment: Do you think your browser is telepathic? How should the computer know to which div it should jump? How should **I** know?

Comment: @yunzen
How about a link like: www.url.com*class[2] 

So instead of using # to link to an id, and instead of using a "css ." (dot) to link to a class (because dot is already used in an url) we use * instead (it looks kind of like a dot), or use any other suitable symbol to specify that it is a class link, but it also MUST contain a number that selects which of many classes that should be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML.

The reason linking to a specific `id`'s location in the page works is because it is expected to be unique, multiple elements can have the same `class`, so which one to link to wouldn't be determinable, and thus you cannot do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid HTML.

There should only ever be unique `id`s on a document - you can't have multiple elements with the same `id` value.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

If you want the specific `div` elements to have the same styling give them all the same class, for example `class="whatever"`.

Comment: @Oded - And I leave my comment then. So drop the matter.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated this is invalid HTML and will not work this way.

**Possible solutions**

- Use different IDs in every `div` and use a link **for each** target

**or**

- Use a class instead of IDs and navigate via script (for example use jQuery's `next()` selector

### jQuery Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/4h6Ly/

*Note that I do not recommend this method for usability reasons! - Of course instead of highlighting you would need to provide the edit function here.*

**HTML**

```
<button id="edit_button">Edit</button>

<div class="edit" >1</div>
<div class="edit" >2</div>
<div class="edit" >3</div>
<div class="edit" >4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active_edit {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#edit_button').click(function() {
    var active = $('.active_edit');

    if (active.length == 0)
        $('.edit').first().addClass('active_edit');
    else {
        $('.active_edit').removeClass('active_edit').next('.edit').addClass('active_edit');
    }
});
```

Comment: how can I use that selector in this case?

Comment: @Fred This would be iterating over the elements. So basically you have to reclick the link until you reached the desired element. -- I'd recommend to change the html structure instead. It doesn't make much sense to have only one edit button for several elements. This is an usability issue, too. Then you'd have to enable editing of all elements within a container. -- I'll append a sample now.

Comment: hmm I still quite dont undertand because my problem is that when doing `href="#edit"` to a `id="edit"`  it always links to the first div to wich I assigned that id. So I need to make that id a class in order for the others to work. I am doing `while() { } echo ""; ` in order for database rows to appear. How do I link to the specify row presented in the div?

Answer (score 1):

If you have acces to the PHP output, give the `ids` a unique suffix, possible source of the suffix is the a unique index in the database, presumably the primary index field, so you have something like this.

```
<a href="#edit-123" >Edit</a>

<div id="edit-341" ></div>
<div id="edit-356" ></div>
<div id="edit-12342" ></div>
<div id="edit-124" ></div>
```

Note: suffices may vary according to the indices

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be a bit outdated for an answer; however, I am new to CSS in general and have not done any html in about 15 years -- I realized a lot has changed as I am now on day 3.  Therefor I apologize if my coding is sloppy or improper.

Regardless, I think I have a solution to this question as I am trying to design a site myself.  This code is branched off a tutorial I found at http://leslievarghese.com/click-events-using-pure-css/.

So, by somewhat *manipulating* the DOM tree, I placed several classes of divs inside multiple ancestors. Then on target I display them.  I hope this technique could be helpful to anyone who may come across this page.

```
<style>
.box{  
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px 0 0;
    max-height:150px;
    max-width:300px;  
    display:none;  
}

#parent:target .box1, #parent2:target .box2, #parent3:target .box{
    display:block;
}  

</style>
<body>  

<a href="#parent">Show Box 1</a>  
<a href="#parent2">Show Box 2</a>  
<a href="#parent3">Show All</a>  
<a href="#hidebox">Hide All</a>  

<div id="parent3">  
<div id="parent2">  
<div id="parent">  

<div class='box box1'> Contents of Box 1 </div>  
<div class="box box2"> Contents of Box 2 </div>  
<div class="box box1"> Contents of Box 1 </div>  
<div class="box box2"> Contents of Box 2 </div>  

</div>  
</div>  
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps.